# recursive checking/copying of files not reaching deeper directory level to check file attributes first

Tags: powershell, recursion, attributes, copy, get-childitem

I'm trying to copy files for a backup script.  I know that the some files aren't going to copy without an error message because of attributes.  I want to log those files and not try to copy them, since it takes forever to fail in the copy.  Plus we want to go back and fix/log or remove any files that don't copy once we find them.

Unfortunately, what I'm trying is finding a deeper subdir, and trying to copy that dir, and it's copying all the files in the dir, when some have an attribute I wouldn't want to copy.  Ex:

> \drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\ and it says it's a good attribute "16"

but there's a file in that dir that the copy is trying to copy over to my dest dir and I'm seeing it has this for attributes:

> file.pdf                    Archive, SparseFile, ReparsePoint, Offline.

I found that by cd to the dir, and using this command:

> dir  | select Name,Attributes

I looked at [recurse not hitting all levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249085/limit-get-childitem-recursion-depth), but I think it's not that recurse isn't hitting all levels, it's that it's copying higher level directories and the files are coming along too, without checking attributes first.

I was looking [how check if path at is dir or file](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/08/31/powertip-using-powershell-to-determine-if-path-is-to-file-or-folder/) for ideas, but when I tried adding the check around the copy, it was skipping adding the dir above the file in it:

```
if(!((Get-Item $_) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo])) #true gives dir, false gives file, only handle if file
```

This is my code right now for the copy function (I tried an exclude but it didn't work):

```
    function CopyFileToFolderUNC($SourcePath, $DestinationPath, $exclude){
       if(-Not (Test-Path $SourcePath )) #-PathType Container
       {
          $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Exception: No such path, $SourcePath;;  ")
          write-output  "++ Error: An error occured during copy operation. No such path, $SourcePath ++"
       }
       #$tempFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($SourcePath)
       #$tempDestFileNamePath = "$DestinationPath\$tempFileName"
       Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath  -Recurse  -Depth 2| ForEach {$_} { #added file removed force -File , $SourcePath\*, $SourcePath\*\* -Depth 3
          #test if maybe we are dealing with an off-line file here
          #or use the enum name 'Offline'
          # or use the numeric value: 4096
          #$oldAttribs = $null
          $attr = $_.Attributes.value__
          write-output  "++ $_ $attr ++"
          if (($_.Attributes -eq [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Offline) -or ($_.Attributes.value__ -eq "4096")) {
             $_.Attributes=[System.IO.FileAttributes]::Normal
             #$oldAttribs = $_.Attributes
             #make it a 'normal' file with only the Archive bit set
             #$_.Attributes = [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive
             #log that the file was an issue and copy the other ones
             $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Found offline file in backup dir, $_. Logging info and not copying this file. Offline. Please investigate.;;  ")
             write-output  "++ Error: An error occured during copy operation. No such path or file, Offline $_ ++"
          } #if
          elseif(($_.Attributes -eq [System.IO.Fileattributes]::Archive) -or ($_.Attributes.value__ -eq "32")) {
             $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Found archive file in backup dir, $_. Logging info and not copying this file. Archive. Please investigate.;;  ")
             write-output  "++ Error: An error occured during copy operation. No such path or file, Archive $_ ++"
          } #elseif
          elseif(($_.Attributes -eq [System.IO.Fileattributes]::SparseFile) -or ($_.Attributes.value__ -eq "512")) {
             $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Found sparse file in backup dir, $_. Logging info and not copying this file. SparseFile. Please investigate.;;  ")
             write-output  "++ Error: An error occured during copy operation. No such path or file, SparseFile $_ ++"
          } #elseif
          elseif(($_.Attributes -eq [System.IO.Fileattributes]::ReparsePoint) -or ($_.Attributes.value__ -eq "1024")) {
             $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Found reparse point file in backup dir, $_. Logging info and not copying this file. ReparsePoint. Please investigate.;;  ")
             write-output  "++ Error: An error occured during copy operation. No such path or file, ReparsePoint $_ ++"
          } #elseif
          elseif( ($_.Attributes.value__ -eq "5664")) { #($_.Attributes -eq [System.IO.Fileattributes]::ReparsePoint) -or
             $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Found reparse point file in backup dir, $_. Logging info and not copying this file. ReparsePoint. Please investigate.;;  ")
             write-output  "++ Error: An error occured during copy operation. No such path or file, ReparsePoint $_ ++"
          } #elseif
          else {

             #the file is not or no longer off-line, so proceed with the copy
             #only if it's a file and not a dir
             #if(!((Get-Item $_) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo])) #true gives dir, false gives file.  We want to copy the files.
             #{
                write-output "Copying $_"
                $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationPath -Force -Recurse -ErrorVariable errors
                foreach($error in $errors)
                {
                  if ($error.Exception -ne $null)
                  {
                      $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Exception: $($error.Exception);;  ")
                      write-output  "++ Error: An error occured during copy operation. Exception: $($error.Exception) ++"
                  }
                  write-output  "Error: An error occured during copy operation. Exception: $($error.Exception)"
                }
             #}
             #else
             #{
             #   write-output "this is a dir"
             #}
          } #else
    } #Get-ChildItem
 } #function
```

This is where it's called from:

```
$tempSource = @("\\drive\Svcs\Cr\C FORMS\",...) 
$ToLocation = @("E:\DisasterBackup\toLoc\All Forms \",...)   
$excludeNonSharepoint = @("\\drive\Svcs\Cred\op\zOLD_NOT USED_keep for now"...)

#non-sharepoint ones first
for($i=0; $i -lt ($tempSource.Length); $i++) {
   CopyFileToFolderUNC $tempSource[$i] $ToLocation[$i] $excludeNonSharepoint
}
```

As requested, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

So for this dir/files/attributes, the copy will complete as follows after checking:

```
source From Location:
\\drive\folder\Forms attrib = normal/16 
\\drive\folder\Forms\a.txt attrib = normal/16 will copy
\\drive\folder\Forms\b.txt attrib = not normal/32/512/1024/etc will not copy  but log
\\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms = normal/16 
\\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\c.txt  attrib = normal/16 will copy
\\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\d.txt attrib = not normal/32/512/1024/etc will not copy but log/write-output
\\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\e.txt attrib = not normal/32/512/1024/etc will not copy but log/write-output
\\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\f.txt attrib = not normal/32/512/1024/etc will not copy but log/write-output
\\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\subdir attribute = normal/16 
\\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\subdir\g.txt  attribute = normal/16 
\\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\subdir\h.txt attribute = not normal/32/512/1024/etc will not copy but log/write-output

final To Location:
E:\DisasterBackup\toLoc\All Forms\a.txt
E:\DisasterBackup\toLoc\All Forms\C Forms
E:\DisasterBackup\toLoc\All Forms\C Forms
E:\DisasterBackup\toLoc\All Forms\C Forms\c.txt
E:\DisasterBackup\toLoc\All Forms\C Forms\subdir\
E:\DisasterBackup\toLoc\All Forms\C Forms\subdir\g.txt  

output string at the end of the script will be something like:
"Could not copy \\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\d.txt attrib archive
Could not copy \\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\e.txt attrib sparse
Could not copy \\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\f.txt attrib reparse
Could not copy \\drive\folder\Forms\C Forms\subdir\h.txt attrib offline"
```

Comment: It's unclear to me if you don't want to copy files with special attributes - or want to copy those files but without the attributes. What about using Robocopy? And please read what a [mcve] is.

Comment: @lotpings - The ones with the bad attributes, I don't want to copy, just log them. I'll add the Minimal/Complete/Verifiable ex to the question.

Comment: Is the real problem permissions on your NAS?

Comment: @trebleCode - The problem with the file attributes is that someone outside our dept. archived the files/etc and we lost a bunch, leaving the mess. We know the mess is there, but want to find new ones once we clean it up. This is what I heard happened before I started.

Comment: @Michele are you stuck with cleaning up the SharePoint files, or do you have a SharePoint admin that can help? Or is that who left?

Comment: @trebleCode - We're copying non-sharepoint files in this question. We aren't sharepoint admins, so have to copy them to a source dir to copy them. We don't have sharepoint powershell plugin. Keep it to non-sharepoint in this question.  Sharepoint files are fine (not corrupt). Thanks!

Comment: It may be useful to mention you [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53946910/9898643) about try his

Comment: Can't you simply use [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) and check its log afterwards?

Comment: @ansgar wiechers - I have a ton of time into the powershell scripts.  It seems like I'm close to finishing and I'd like to figure out my current question.

Comment: @theo, none of the answers worked in the other question. I thought that since the question was a couple or more weeks old, I should try to re-ask a little differently. Thanks for your help!!